# Why is my variable not incrementing? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm learning JavaScript and having difficulties. Why doesn't this increment number when circle is pressed and gone? I tried adding `return counter;` but it did nothing.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="circle" id="red-circle"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="green-circle"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="blue-circle"></div>

    <div id="hiddenTxt">
        <p> </p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let counter = 0;

        document.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = function (counter) {
            document.getElementById("red-circle").style.display = "none";
            counter++;
        }
        document.getElementById("green-circle").onclick = function (counter) {
            document.getElementById("green-circle").style.display = "none";
            counter++;
        }
        document.getElementById("blue-circle").onclick = function (counter) {
            document.getElementById("blue-circle").style.display = "none";
            counter++;
        }
        console.log('here 1');
        console.log(counter);

        if (counter === 3) {
            console.log('here 2');
            document.getElementById("hiddenTxt").innerHTML = 'You did it!';
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to fix this for an hour. I originally tried

```
        if (document.getElementById("red-circle").style.display === "none" &&
            document.getElementById("green-circle").style.display === "none" &&
             document.getElementById("blue-circle").style.display === "none") {

             console.log('here');
             document.getElementById("hiddenTxt").innerHTML = 'You did it!';
         }
```

Comment: You have shadowed the counter variable in each of your click handlers. The parameter passed to your click handlers is not the outer `counter` variable at all. The parameter passed to each handler is actually the source `event` that triggered the handler. Change `counter` in each callback declaration to `event`, or simply remove counter from each declaration (because you're not using the passed event).

Comment: @jarmod Sorry, I don't understand what that means. So where should I put my counters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be one possible implementation that achieves the objective:

```js
let counter = 0;

document.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("red-circle").style.display = "none";
  counter++;
  showText();
}
document.getElementById("green-circle").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("green-circle").style.display = "none";
  counter++;
  showText();
}
document.getElementById("blue-circle").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("blue-circle").style.display = "none";
  counter++;
  showText();
}
const showText = () => {
  if (counter === 3) {
    console.log('here 2');
    document.getElementById("hiddenTxt").innerHTML = 'You did it!';
  }
};
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.green {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.blue {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle red" id="red-circle">1</div>
  <div class="circle green" id="green-circle">2</div>
  <div class="circle blue" id="blue-circle">3</div>

  <div id="hiddenTxt"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**An alternative approach may be something like this**

```js
let counter = 0;

// Removed repeated statements and moved into 'handleClick' with parameter
const handleClick = clickedColor => {
  document.getElementById(clickedColor).style.display = "none";
  counter++;
  if (counter === 3) {
    document.getElementById("hiddenTxt").innerHTML = 'You did it!';
  }
};

// Removed individual onclick by using an array
['red-circle', 'green-circle', 'blue-circle'].forEach(
  colorOption => {
    document.getElementById(colorOption).onclick = () => handleClick(colorOption);
    }
);
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.green {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.blue {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle red" id="red-circle">1</div>
  <div class="circle green" id="green-circle">2</div>
  <div class="circle blue" id="blue-circle">3</div>

  <div id="hiddenTxt"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am updating the answer with another approach. One, which may be more appealing to some developers. Please give me few minutes.

Comment: Seems interesting. Thank you for writing an alternative method too!

Comment: Happy to help. The issue was with making the function-call with `counter` as a parameter. And, by not invoking the `if (counter === 3)` on each of those 3 `onclick` events. By removing the parameter, `counter` referred to the variable declared using `let` at line-1. And, by using `showText()` method, the `if` was evaluated on each of those 3 `onclick` events. Let me know if you need a break-down of the alternative approach, please.

Answer (score 0):

*The reason for that you're giving your `function (counter)` argument and it's actually nothing remove counter argument and it will work*

```js
let counter = 0;
document.getElementById("blue-circle").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("blue-circle").style.display = "none";
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Hello, sadly this didn't fix it. I see on console that `````counter```` doesn't change from 0

Comment: and you will not see the updates in the `console` because it will print this one time if you want to see **updates** in `counter variable` add `console.log(counter)` inside your function insted.

Comment: like this
`let counter = 0;
document.getElementById("blue-circle").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("blue-circle").style.display = "none";
    counter++;
   console.log(counter)
}`

Comment: Thanks, counter is 3 but it still doesn't run the code in the if statement.

Comment: do the same thing in your if statement put it inside your function, or create a separate function and do `function counter(...) {...}` and add it to the **onClick event** like this `document.getElementById("blue-circle").onclick = counter`

Answer (score 0):

the onclick take the event as a parameter but you name it counter the same as the global variable that you used!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
let counter = 0;
const hiddenTxt = document.getElementById("hiddenTxt");
const redCircle = document.getElementById("red-circle");
redCircle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter++;
  redCircle.style.display = "none";
  if (counter === 3) {
    console.log('here 2');
    hiddenTxt.innerHTML = 'You did it!';
  }
}) 

const greenCircle = document.getElementById("green-circle");
greenCircle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter++;
  greenCircle.style.display = "none";
  if (counter === 3) {
    console.log('here 2');
    hiddenTxt.innerHTML = 'You did it!';
  }
}) 

const blueCircle = document.getElementById("blue-circle");
blueCircle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter++;
  blueCircle.style.display = "none";
  if (counter === 3) {
    console.log('here 2');
    hiddenTxt.innerHTML = 'You did it!';
  }
}) 

    </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, didn't seem to do anything different. But thanks for replying

Comment: the if statement should be recall when the user click again

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    counter = 0;
    function increment(callback) {
        counter++;
        callback();
        if (counter === 3) {
            console.log('here 2');
            document.getElementById("hiddenTxt").innerHTML = 'You did it!';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = () => increment(() =>   document.getElementById("red-circle").style.display = "none")
    document.getElementById("green-circle").onclick = () => increment(() => document.getElementById("green-circle").style.display = "none")
    document.getElementById("blue-circle").onclick = () => increment(() => document.getElementById("blue-circle").style.display = "none")

</script>
```